# Can we delete the second "Whether" after "or" and simplify the sentence? Why is the "Whether" after "or"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

He had only to consider whether he would employ art or violence, or whether he would rather prefer a judicious admixture of the two.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/using-whether-twice-in-a-sentence-whether-a-or-whether-b.2448301/  (As you already have an **or** before **violence**, in this case I'd use a second **whether** to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think the neatest way of avoiding confusion is to "focus" the readers attention by including ***indeed*** before the second instance of ***whether***. That second instance "unexpectedly" converts the two preceding options into ***the first possibility***, as part of a new context juxtaposing ***either*** OR ***both*** instead of ***one*** OR ***the other***, so it certainly does no harm to throw in ***indeed*** to make sure the reader pays attention to that "switcheroo".

Comment: (In case it's not obvious, ***my*** opinion is that you definitely ***shouldn't*** consider discarding the second instance of ***whether***. In fact, it's so important it should be made even more emphatic by introducing it with attention-grabbing ***indeed***. :)